# Não aparece os alinhamentos automáticos dos componentes no Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio

Sabe quando você arrasta, por exemplo, um `textbox` para um local e um outro para outro local, e o Visual Studio acaba alinhando automaticamente para você, para que o `form` fique mais organizado?

Eu utilizo o Visual Studio 2013 e ele parou com essa funcionalidade de repente.
Alguma maneira de ativar essa opção?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Vá em **Tools** > **Options...** > **Windows Forms Designer**;
- Verifique se as opções assinaladas estão marcadas:

[image: Snap]

Comment: Estão marcadas sim... O estranho é que as vezes o Visual trava e preciso reiniciá-lo.